# Using least squares to extract a Fourier approximation

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, fast-fourier-transform, fourier-restriction

I am faced with the following problem. I have signal $x_t:\{0,1,N-1\} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ where $N$ is very large. I want to compute a few of the Fourier coefficients say for example:$\hat{x}_0, \hat{x}_1, \hat{x}_2$. Since $N$ is prohibitively large I don't want to use the Fourier analysis equation and I don't want to look at the whole signal.
I take the following approach, I vectorize $x$ and $\hat{x}$ and I let $\mathcal{F} \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$ denote the matrix that holds the Fourier basis as its columns. It holds that:
$$x = \mathcal{F} \hat{x}, \;\;\;\ \hat{x} = \mathcal{F}^{-1} x $$
One thing I could do now is compute the least square solution to get these three coefficients:
$$\hat{x}_{0:3} = \arg\min_{\theta \in \mathbb{C^3}}\|x-F_{:,0:3} \theta\|$$
Where the equality above is exact. But again this would require me to read the whole signal. I am now wondering what happens if I subsample some rows of the vector $x$ and rows of the Fourier matrix uniformly at random, say I subsample 10 rows and solve the corresponding (still overdetermined), least squares system. What kind of theoretical guarantees could I give?

Comment: If you are looking for low frequencies, did you try to sample your data? By that I mean that instead of taking all the points, you take 1 in 2 points, or 1 in 3 and so on until your resulting number of points is not prohibitively large anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not looking for just low frequencies, rather I want three of the coefficients that may even be high frequency so I am not considering the downsampling schemes that you mentioned. I was looking for an answer based on RIP properties of the Fourier matrix for example

Comment: Unless you add some more information to the signal I'm not sure it can be done. For instance, think of a signal composed of 2 signals, one after the other. The first has information up to frequency $ {f}_{1} $ and the other only above $ {f}_{1} $. Then, how could you know it without going through all samples? You need assumptions on the signal model, otherwise, for any idea one could build a signal which makes the idea useless.

Comment: Yes you are right. Say that I make the assumption that three frequencies f_1,f_2,f_3  capture 90 percent of the energy of the whole signal. How would u proceed then.

Comment: Maybe this?: Let $F$ denote the Fourier transform, and let $u=(1,0,\ldots,0)\in\mathbb{C}^N$. Then, e.g. the $0$th Fourier coefficient can be written via the inner product $\langle Fx\,|\ u\rangle$. However, this is equal to $\langle x\, |\, F^*u\rangle$ where $F^*$ is the adjoint (i.e. IFFT). It feels like you could probably find $F^*u$ in closed form and then compute that inner product quite quickly.

Comment: What you have written basically results in the Fourier analysis equation which is exactly wha I am trying to avoid